# SQL - randomizing existing values with a specific list of values

Tags: mysql, variables

I have 3 tables involved in this issue :

[person_attribute_type]

```
+--------------------------+-------------+
| person_attribute_type_id | foreign_key |
+--------------------------+-------------+
|                       16 |         694 |
|                       25 |         178 |
|                       27 |         177 |
|                       28 |         163 |
+--------------------------+-------------+
```

[concept_answer]

```
+------------+----------------+
| concept_id | answer_concept |
+------------+----------------+
|        163 |            342 |
|        163 |            343 |
|        163 |            251 |
|        163 |            253 |
|        163 |            320 |
|        163 |            322 |
|        163 |            408 |
|        177 |            408 |
|        177 |            254 |
|        177 |            255 |
|        177 |            256 |
|        177 |            344 |
|        177 |            257 |
|        178 |            229 |
|        178 |            345 |
|        178 |            346 |
|        178 |            347 |
|        178 |            348 |
|        694 |            692 |
|        694 |            685 |
|        694 |            689 |
|        694 |            690 |
|        694 |            687 |
|        694 |            684 |
|        694 |            693 |
|        694 |            686 |
|        694 |            688 |
|        694 |            691 |
+------------+----------------+
```

(concept_id: it's the same value contained in person_attribute_type.foreign_key)

[person_attribute]

```
+--------------------------+-------+

| person_attribute_type_id | value |
+--------------------------+-------+
|                       16 | 688   |
|                       25 | 348   |
|                       27 | 256   |
|                       28 | 251   |
|                       16 | 687   |
|                       25 | 348   |
|                       27 | 408   |
|                       28 | 342   |
|                       16 | 684   |
|                       25 | 345   |
|                       27 | 408   |
|                       28 | 343   |
|                       16 | 687   |
|                       25 | 347   |
|                       27 | 344   |
|                       28 | 342   |
|                       16 | 684   |
|                       25 | 346   |
|                       27 | 254   |
|                       28 | 320   |
|                       16 | 693   |
|                       25 | 347   |
|                       27 | 344   |
|                       28 | 342   |
|                       16 | 687   |
|                       25 | 345   |
|                       27 | 254   |
|                       28 | 251   |
|                       16 | 690   |
|                       25 | 347   |
|                       27 | 408   |
|                       28 | 251   |
|                       16 | 687   |
|                       25 | 229   |
|                       27 | 257   |
|                       28 | 342   |
|                       16 | 689   |
|                       25 | 348   |
|                       27 | 408   |
|                       28 | 322   |
|                       16 | 688   |
|                       25 | 347   |
|                       27 | 256   |
|                       28 | 342   |
|                       16 | 684   |
|                       25 | 345   |
|                       27 | 344   |
|                       28 | 343   |
|                       16 | 689   |
|                       25 | 348   |
```

(value: it's the same value contained in concept_answer.answer_concept)

--

I want to randomize person_attribute.value with concept_answer.answer_concept and its person_attribute_type_id, within its acceptable list of answers.

I hope it's understandable..

So this is what I did:

```
-- Getting the variables for each line of person_attribute_type_id & foreign key

SELECT person_attribute_type_id, foreign_key INTO @pati1, @fk1 FROM person_attribute_type LIMIT 0,1;
SELECT person_attribute_type_id, foreign_key INTO @pati2, @fk2 FROM person_attribute_type LIMIT 1,1;
SELECT person_attribute_type_id, foreign_key INTO @pati3, @fk3 FROM person_attribute_type LIMIT 2,1;
SELECT person_attribute_type_id, foreign_key INTO @pati4, @fk4 FROM person_attribute_typeLIMIT 3,1;

-- Getting manually all the answers linked to the foreign_key

SET @answers1:=(select answer_concept FROM concept_answer WHERE concept_id = @fk1 LIMIT 0,1);
SET @answers2:=(select answer_concept FROM concept_answer WHERE concept_id = @fk1 LIMIT 1,1);
SET @answers3:=(select answer_concept FROM concept_answer WHERE concept_id = @fk1 LIMIT 2,1);
SET @answers4:=(select answer_concept FROM concept_answer WHERE concept_id = @fk1 LIMIT 3,1);
SET @answers5:=(select answer_concept FROM concept_answer WHERE concept_id = @fk1 LIMIT 4,1);
SET @answers6:=(select answer_concept FROM concept_answer WHERE concept_id = @fk1 LIMIT 5,1);
SET @answers7:=(select answer_concept FROM concept_answer WHERE concept_id = @fk1 LIMIT 6,1);
SET @answers8:=(select answer_concept FROM concept_answer WHERE concept_id = @fk1 LIMIT 7,1);
SET @answers9:=(select answer_concept FROM concept_answer WHERE concept_id = @fk1 LIMIT 8,1);
SET @answers10:=(select answer_concept FROM concept_answer WHERE concept_id = @fk1 LIMIT 9,1);

SET @2answers1:=(select answer_concept FROM concept_answer WHERE concept_id = @fk2 LIMIT 0,1);
SET @2answers2:=(select answer_concept FROM concept_answer WHERE concept_id = @fk2 LIMIT 1,1);
SET @2answers3:=(select answer_concept FROM concept_answer WHERE concept_id = @fk2 LIMIT 2,1);
SET @2answers4:=(select answer_concept FROM concept_answer WHERE concept_id = @fk2 LIMIT 3,1);
SET @2answers5:=(select answer_concept FROM concept_answer WHERE concept_id = @fk2 LIMIT 4,1);

SET @3answers1:=(select answer_concept FROM concept_answer WHERE concept_id = @fk3 LIMIT 0,1);
SET @3answers2:=(select answer_concept FROM concept_answer WHERE concept_id = @fk3 LIMIT 1,1);
SET @3answers3:=(select answer_concept FROM concept_answer WHERE concept_id = @fk3 LIMIT 2,1);
SET @3answers4:=(select answer_concept FROM concept_answer WHERE concept_id = @fk3 LIMIT 3,1);
SET @3answers5:=(select answer_concept FROM concept_answer WHERE concept_id = @fk3 LIMIT 4,1);
SET @3answers6:=(select answer_concept FROM concept_answer WHERE concept_id = @fk3 LIMIT 5,1);

SET @4answers1:=(select answer_concept FROM concept_answer WHERE concept_id = @fk4 LIMIT 0,1);
SET @4answers2:=(select answer_concept FROM concept_answer WHERE concept_id = @fk4 LIMIT 1,1);
SET @4answers3:=(select answer_concept FROM concept_answer WHERE concept_id = @fk4 LIMIT 2,1);
SET @4answers4:=(select answer_concept FROM concept_answer WHERE concept_id = @fk4 LIMIT 3,1);
SET @4answers5:=(select answer_concept FROM concept_answer WHERE concept_id = @fk4 LIMIT 4,1);
SET @4answers6:=(select answer_concept FROM concept_answer WHERE concept_id = @fk4 LIMIT 5,1);
SET @4answers7:=(select answer_concept FROM concept_answer WHERE concept_id = @fk4 LIMIT 6,1);

-- Randomize and update the values for person_attribute.value according to the "possible list of answers" for each concept_id

UPDATE person_attribute SET value = ELT(FLOOR(1 + RAND() * 10), @answers1, @answers2, @answers3, @answers4, @answers5, @answers6, @answers7, @answers8, @answers9, @answers10) WHERE person_attribute_type_id = @pati1;
UPDATE person_attribute SET value = ELT(FLOOR(1 + RAND() * 5), @2answers1, @2answers2, @2answers3, @2answers4, @2answers5) WHERE person_attribute_type_id = @pati2;
UPDATE person_attribute SET value = ELT(FLOOR(1 + RAND() * 6), @3answers1, @3answers2, @3answers3, @3answers4, @3answers5, @3answers6) WHERE person_attribute_type_id = @pati3;
UPDATE person_attribute SET value = ELT(FLOOR(1 + RAND() * 7), @4answers1, @4answers2, @4answers3, @4answers4, @4answers5, @4answers6, @4answers7) WHERE person_attribute_type_id = @pati4;
```

The question is: I'm sure there's an easier non manual and shorter way to reach the same result. Does anybody know ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The easiest way to achieve what you want in MySQL is to `SELECT rand_val FROM tbl WHERE conditions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`. This gives you a single random value based on a given set of values. From there you can build more complex queries as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve what you want in MySQL is to `SELECT rand_val FROM tbl WHERE conditions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`. This gives you a single random value based on a given set of values. From there you can build more complex queries as needed.

Applied to your example it would be something like

```
UPDATE person_attribute t
SET value = 
(SELECT answer_concept 
  FROM person_attribute_type t2  
  LEFT JOIN concept_answer t3 
  ON t2.foreign_key=t3.concept_id 
  WHERE t2.person_attribute_type_id = t.person_attribute_type_id 
  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1);
```

which should replace your entire SQL script and update all the rows in one go.